# I want to replace special symbol to another text in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the characters at once, but it doesn't change when I use the special symbol like [ or ( or : or - . What should I do?

my sample datatable is below

```
df


   col1
0  ( red ) apple
1  [ 20220901 ] autumn
2  - gotohome
3  sample : salt bread
```

and I want to get this below

```
df

   col1
0  red
   apple
1  20220901 
   autumn
2  gotohome
3  sample
   salt bread
```

my trial is below but it's not working.

```
change_word = {
    '( red )'        : 'red\n', 
    '[ 20220901 ]'   : '20220901\n',
    '- '             : '', 
    ':'              : '\n'
}

regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(change_word.keys()) + r')\b'
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(regex, lambda m: change_word[m.group()], regex=True)
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Is there an exception? Unexpected result? What does m.group() return? Basically what you have to do is escape the special characters like (, ), [, ] because regex. Use r'\( red \)' etc. and try again.

Comment: Use \[ , \], \( and \) instead of [, ], (, ) in the change word dictionary.
E.g. `print(re.sub( r'(\( red \)|\[ 20220901 \])', 'RED', "( red ) apple [ 20220901 ] autumn"))`
replaces (red) and [ 20220901 ] with RED.
Instead of a lambda function I would define a replace function as a normal function with a loop in it, and I would use apply.  But I'm not an expert of pandas.

Comment: I forgot: use row strings in the keywords of the change_word dictionary, otherwise instead of \[  you should write \\[  as a normal string containing a backslash is "\\", but with row string it is just r"\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use something like:

```
import re

badchars = '()[]\t-:'
df2  = (df['col1']
        .str.strip(badchars+' ') # strip unwanted chars at extremities
        .str.split(f'\s*[{re.escape(badchars)}]+\s*') # split on badchars + spaces
        .explode().to_frame() # explode as new rows
       )
```

Output:

```
         col1
0         red
0       apple
1    20220901
1      autumn
2    gotohome
3      sample
3  salt bread
```